# How do I accessing siblings from an Item inside a ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="TopicList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:TopicListItem Title="{Binding Title}" LocationCloud="{Binding Locations}" TagCloudData="{Binding TagCloudData}" SparklineData="{Binding SparklineData}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Then I get some XML and turn that into an `IEnumerable<ListObj>` using LINQ which is then attached to `TopicList.ItemsSource`. As you see the only element in the list is a UseControl that I made myself called `TopicListItem`. I want to be able to access the index of items that the ItemsControl has from the `TopicListItem.xaml.cs` file so that as I click on one of them to perform an open action, I can close the rest.

Thanks for the help :)

(and I have tried Accordion and AccordionItems, to stiff for my taste :D )

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer it myself since I got some help within the company.

The way I did it was to simply access the ItemsControl elemement and get the collection from the `Items` property.

```
MainPage root = Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage;
foreach(MyClass c in root.TopicList.Items) 
{
    // loop through them all and close/open conditionally
}
```

I hope this help anyone else.